# Cannot remove server in response headers (Amazon AWS)

Tags: http-headers, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, apache

I cannot remove the "Server" header from the response headers. I am using Amazon EC2. I have added this in Apache config:

```
ServerSignature Off
Header unset Server
RequestHeader unset Server
```

It does not do anything. I can still see the server header saying "Apache (Amazon)" in the response headers. Any clue?

Comment: Unless you're using something other than EC2 (like ELB), then the fact that you're using EC2 is irrelevant. It's a bare server, and server configuration questions -> ServerFault.com.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the "Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) ..." line in the header as follows:

Download the Apache httpd tarball and unpack it in the usual way.

Change include/ap_release.h from:

```
#define AP_SERVER_BASEVENDOR "Apache Software Foundation"
#define AP_SERVER_BASEPROJECT "Apache HTTP Server"
#define AP_SERVER_BASEPRODUCT "Apache"
```

to

```
#define AP_SERVER_BASEVENDOR "-"
#define AP_SERVER_BASEPROJECT "-"
#define AP_SERVER_BASEPRODUCT "-"
```

Then recompile with your usual configure / make / make install procedure.

Finally, in your httpd.conf file, include the line:

```
ServerTokens Prod
```

Restart your server and the Apache header line will simply become "Server: -" .

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Apache dev team think this is work as design.
Anyway they provide a patch https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40026